# create sublist and sort in Tcl

Tags: sorting, split, tcl

I need to sort a sentence which is random in order. Each word in a sentence has an index value.
e.g
set sentence "will2 out4 Things1 work3"
Output="Things will work out"

I tried using `lsort -index 1 {{will 2} {out 4} {Things 1} {work 3}}`
This will give output as `{Things 1} {will 2} {work 3} {out 4}`
I need help to create sublist and split the Input sentence to enable it for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing of a word into its text and index part can be done with `regexp` (`\D` matches a non-digit, and `\d` matches a digit):

```
regexp {(\D+)(\d+)} $word -> text index
```

You then can either use this by transforming the list or by making auxiliary lists for sorting purposes.

In performance terms, these two techniques are *incredibly* similar on your sample input (assuming the obvious conversions to procedures) with less than 1% difference in timing. Either they're doing the same amount of work really, or they're making similar mistakes in terms of excess effort.

### Sorting by list transformation

```
set input "will2 out4 Things1 work3"
set prepared [lmap word $input {
    lrange [regexp -inline {(\D+)(\d+)} $word] 1 end
}]
set sorted [lsort -integer -index 1 $prepared]
set output [lmap pair $sorted {
    lindex $pair 0
}]
# Converting that into a one-liner is left as an obvious exercise
```

## Sorting with auxiliary lists

This uses the `-indices` option to `lsort`, which tells you what order the values in the list would be sorted into; this is great if you want to apply that order to something else.

```
set input "will2 out4 Things1 work3"
set texts [set values {}]
foreach word $input {
    regexp {(\D+)(\d+)} $word -> t v
    lappend texts $t
    lappend values $v
}
set sorted [lsort -indices -integer $values]
set output [lmap idx $sorted {
    lindex $texts $idx
}]
```

Comment: Hmm, more performance testing indicates that the first version is a bit faster after all (approaching 10% difference). But it's still microbenchmarking, and so the uncertainty remains; I'd need a range of larger inputs to do better analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first turn your words into a list of pairs that can be sorted with `lsort`, and then extract just the word part to re-join them into a sentence. It's a slight variation of what's known as the **decorate-sort-undecorate** operation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set sentence "will2 out4 Things1 work3"

# Turn sentence into a list of pairs of the words and numbers
set pairs [lmap word [split $sentence] {
    regexp {([[:alpha:]]+)(\d+)$} $word -> w n
    list $w $n    
}]

# Sort based on number much like you're doing in your question
set pairs [lsort -index 1 -integer $pairs]

# And re-join the first elements of the pairs
set sentence [join [lmap pair $pairs { lindex $pair 0 }]]

puts $sentence
```

If you do it all in one step without intermediate variables, it's known as a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) (Though in this case I think readability suffers):

```
set sentence [join [lmap pair [lsort -index 1 -integer \
                                   [lmap word [split $sentence] {
                                       regexp {([[:alpha:]]+)(\d+)$} $word -> w n
                                       list $w $n
                                   }]] { lindex $pair 0 }]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sentence has nine or fewer words, you can reverse each word with `lmap`, sort on the reversed words, then un-reverse.

```
set sentence "will2 out4 Things1 work3"
                                    
set ecnetnes [lmap word $sentence {string reverse $word}]

set sorted_ecnetnes [lsort $ecnetnes]

set sorted_sentence [lmap word $sorted_ecnetnes {string range [string reverse $word] 0 end-1}]

--> Things will work out
```